# SQLite Google Colab database

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I tried to add values to a sqlite database but get OperationalError: no such table: BANDS. The file appears in colab but it cannot be called. Im not sure if this is an issue with colab or file path.I've looked through other questions and answers, but none satisfy my issue. I am a beginner so any suggestions will be useful.

```
import sqlite3
connect = sqlite3.connect('BANDS.db')
    cursor_obj = connect.cursor()
table = """create table IF NOT EXISTS INSTRUCTOR(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Band_Name VARCHAR(20), Start_Year VARCHAR(20), CITY VARCHAR(20));"""

cursor_obj.execute(table)

print("Table is Ready")

cursor_obj.execute('''insert into BANDS values(1, "Black Flag", "1976", "Hermosa Beach"), (2, "King GIzzard", "2010", "Melbourne" ), (3, "Metallica", "1981", "Los Angles")''')
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Change the creation statement to create the table called `BANDS` that you want.

```
table = """create table IF NOT EXISTS BANDS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, Band_Name VARCHAR(20), Start_Year VARCHAR(20), CITY VARCHAR(20));"""
```